# SSH always connects to the same IP address

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, dns, sshd

No matter what the host is, SSH keeps trying to connect to `162.13.177.241`.

Command

```
ssh -v user@host
```

Output

```
debug1: Connecting to 162.13.177.241 [162.13.177.241] port 22.
```

My `/etc/hosts` file is empty, and I can't seem to find an answer to this.

I have tried to restart `sshd` with no success.

Should mention I am running **Linux Mint 17 Qiana**.

Really don't know where to take this. Any direction for troubleshooting would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: Also cleared `~/.ssh/config`

**Edit**: Turns out I thought `~/.ssh/config` was cleared when it really wasn't. Clearing it solved the problem...

Comment: Do you have anything in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: Nope, cleared that, too.

Comment: `ssh -v user@host -p 2222` does IP stay the same, only port change in trace?

Comment: IP still stays the same but port changes.

Comment: Is this _just_ ssh? What does running `host host` say? What about `host -a host`?

Comment: At the end, are you able to connect to the said `host` system as in `user@host` ? If yes and if this is in a corporate environment, I'd suspect your company is doing stateful packet inspection to see the type of communication you are trying to establish and have a captive gateway for outgoing ssh connections. It wouldn't be too far fetched to assume, the communication is being recorded and logged, in case of a future incident.

Comment: Thanks for the questions. To answer the last two:
1. it's just ssh. `host host` returns the correct IP.
2. I can't connect to the said `host` using ssh.

Comment: `telnet host 22` prints `Trying...` what address?

Comment: and check if you are really running `ssh` not some wrapper `which ssh` or alias `\ssh -v user@host`

Comment: Did you try to restart the nameservice cache (nscd)?

Comment: @Lambert Haven't tried restarting the nameservice cache yet.

@techraf `telnet` tries and connects to the correct host. How do I check if it's a wrapper? using `which` points to `/usr/bin/ssh`.

Comment: Is it your system? Did you set it up yourself or use some image? 162.13.177.241 is Rackspace address space, is it another of your machines?

Comment: Set up the laptop myself. Just a basic mint install. Worked fine for over a year. None of our servers are pointing to that IP. Makes me think I might have some obscure config with an old IP on it.

Comment: Also, `ssh` traffic doesn't appear on `tcpdump`, but traffic from `telnet` does.

Comment: Clearing `nscd` cache also didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you cleared out:  `.ssh\known_hosts` as this hold the IP per domain

Comment: If you disconnect from network, reboot, and try `ssh -v user@host` does it resolve the name to 162.13.177.241?

Comment: Apologies on my part. The solution was a faulty `~/.ssh/config` file. I left out the `Host` line for a block in the config. Thought I cleared out the config file. Pretty sure I did, but must have not saved it before testing the `ssh -v user@host` command. Sorry for this, and thanks for all your help. Learned a lot with this!

Comment: Now that's enough info to post an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshoot the problem:

1. You should make sure ssh does not have any custom configuration in `~/.ssh/config`

   The best way would be to temporarily move the file out of the way by renaming it (do not rely on editing the content and believing it should be ok, you are troubleshooting anyway):

   ```
   mv -i ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/config_
   ```

---

The above (as we know from comments) was enough to isolate the problem, however if it wasn't:

2. Check `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for any individual host settings. By default only `Host *` section exists.
3. If still some redirection occur isolate step by step:

   1. Check the results of `telnet host 22` and compare the result with `ssh` - if the destination IP is redirected in both cases, it would point to some strange network redirection.
   2. Disconnect machine from network and check redirection, if occurs, then the problem is on machine. If not (unlikely) check network environment, proxies, DNS, etc.
   3. Use / create new user and check `ssh` from different account, if redirection does not occur, recheck individual settings of original user.
   4. Check if you are running original `ssh` with the following commands:

      ```
      $ which ssh
      /usr/bin/ssh
      $ file /usr/bin/ssh
      /usr/bin/ssh: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=3ec70221b7cac9eebe63dadbe871bc49359a7dfe, stripped
      ```

      If the results are different you might be running a shell wrapper executing `ssh` with parameters defined in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do a Filtered pcap of the traffic.  That's a dangerous authentication, especially if it appears to have and auto-route.